# Selenium Grid E2E test deployment into Github Action

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, github-actions

I have suite of selenium tests written in RobotFramework and run with Pabot, right now, it deploys into Jenkins cluster, with Selenium Grid setup. Both the Jenkins cluster and Selenium Grid are deployed into Kubernetes cluster.

While the setup for the testing infra is complicated, I wonder anyone

I wonder if I can completely migrate this E2E test setup into Github Action deployment.